# structure of menu with stucture (3.3.13)

Tags: structure

i'm working on a website with structure ( 3.3.13) and expression engine (2.7.2). I'm struggling with the menu. The html of the menu has to be like the image (with the same classes and data options):

[image]

Can i create this menu with structure?

Answer (score 2):

If the native [Entries](http://buildwithstructure.com/tags#tag_entries) method doesn't suit your need, [Structure Entries](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-entries) will solve your problem.